# Flash Builder 4.6 linked Resources not working with ANEs and Certs

Tags: flash-builder

I'm having an issue with linked Resources in Flash Builder. I work in a team environment where we use Linked Resources extensively. We just started developing ANEs and noticed that while linkedResources are used in the libraryPathEntry, in the buildTargets like anePathEntry and airCertificatePath, the absolute path is stored. I tried editing the .actionScriptProperties files directly, modifying the buildtarget absolute paths to linked resource equivalents using the libraryPathEntry as a guide but FlashBuilder complained when loading the project.

Is there a way to get the buildTargets to respect linkedResources and not save the absolute path? I'm trying to avoid the draconian way where all developers must have the exact same directory structure.

Thanks!

Randy

Answer (score 1):

My team had this exact problem and all attempts to fix it with relative paths or workspace macros (i.e. ${PROJECT_LOC}) failed.  It seems as if the team in charge of Flash Builder neglected to support relative paths in these particular dialogs, despite them being supported elsewhere.

Here is what we have done to fix this problem.  I am assuming you are on a Mac/Linux or the like.  If not, the concept here can still be applied.

Most of our projects already have a "set up" bash script that contributors run when they get code.  Inside of that script, we simply set up a couple of symbolic links from the user specific absolute path, to a new absolute path with a "common" user.  The script first creates the directory if it does not exist, and then creates the symlinks.

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/common/<project>/
sudo ln -f -h -s ~/path/to/certificate/dir /Users/common/<project>/certificates
```

*Obviously you can use whatever you like and whatever makes sense for the common path.*

Now, in your .actionScriptProperties file you can change the location pointed to by the provisingFile and airCertificatePath to this new common absolute path.

```
<buildTarget ... provisioningFile="/Users/common/<project>/certificates/provisionfile.mobileprovision" ... >
<airSettings airCertificatePath="/Users/common/<project>/certificates/cert.p12" ... >
```

We actually take this a step further (and I suspect you will need to also) and create common symlink paths for the ANE files themselves.  This ends up changing the anePathEntry to the common path as well.

```
<anePathEntry path="/Users/common/<project>/anes/some.ane"/>
```

- You will need to make sure that you either hand edit the .actionScriptProperties file directly, or type in the fully qualified symlink path into the dialogs directly.  Any attempt at using the Finder dialog launched by Flash Builder to navigate to the files in the common location resulted in the symlinks being auto-resolved to their actual locations.
- The script requires sudo, which as I'm sure you know, will require that the users of it know their root password.  Maybe some more bash savvy folks can suggest a way around sudo if this is not an option for you.
- This will work for android stuff as well I believe.  I don't know if that matters to you or not.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue was called out in the Flash Builder 4.6 known issues:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/flash-builder-4-6-known.html

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-32955

The bug is apparently fixed but I haven't been able to check the new Flash Builder 4.7 beta yet:

http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2012/08/flash-builder-4-7-beta-is-here.html